Bunch of "boxes"
What symbol must replace the question mark in order to get a 7-letter word that describes this puzzle?






Note: Ignore the different size/thickness of the symbols (using phone)
Hint 1

 It's based on something very simple.


I believe the answer is

 SQUARES and the symbol that goes on the top is 00.

Reason

 These are simply reflections of square numbers 1,4,9 along the y axis so the beginning of the sequence has the be the perfect square before 1 which is 0 and reflecting 0 we get 00.

As for the title

 What is a box but a square.


Yes this is it, well done :)
